# What detail must a UML class diagram have?

Tags: java, class, uml, diagram

To design a project and draw a UML class diagram, what must the class diagram include?

1. Suppose our classes have textfields, buttons etc. Must they be included as members?
2. Suppose we need to perform some form validations, and we intend to perform it by passing data obtained from a form to a "validator" object, must it be also included in the class diagram?

I received some opinions from colleagues that a class diagram is for design phase and must not include objects like I mentioned above. However when the project completes, won't there be a large number of objects we did not draw in the class diagram?

Comment: Is this for work or school?  Generally a professor/boss will let you know how much detail they want.

Comment: UML is a communication tool. It's not a development tool. It isn't supposed to contain the absolute reality of the code. The code already contains this absolute reality. Use it as a way to document and communicate the big picture. And use it when it's necessary. When the code and its documentation is self sufficient, no need for diagrams. When some piece of the app is complex and benefits from a visual explanation, then use diagrams.

Comment: effective fields and main methods for each class should be provided,However it mainly depends on how precise you prof is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UML is a language. The way you use it is up to you.

Ideally you will have multiple documents. The reason you will need multiple documents is because the most important tip of documentation writing is to restrict yourself to one perspective per document.

You want a static representation of objects -> don't talk about files
You want to show relations between objects -> don't talk about data flow.

You get the idea. As long as you are clear with what the purpose of the document is and consistent to the legend, UML can tell any story.

**For your specific question:**
Since you're creating a class diagram (a static representation of system objects), the important bits will likely be what goes into each object/class (not the input fields of the form itself, but the structure of the object those fields are eventually saved to), and how they relate to other objects.

You can include the validator object and connect it to the objects its validating, but modeling how it's validating, when it's validating, or the protocol with which they communicate is not relevant for this specific view.

Answer (score 1):

Generally in UML diagrams, you exclude extraneous data.  Depending on how in-depth you want to be, things such as a UI controls and getter/setter methods are usually excluded.

On the other hand, your `Validator` object should be defined as a control class in your UML diagram, as it has a responsibility and purpose within your system.